# Does calling @Bean methods create a new instance of the object or the bean instance?

Tags: java, spring

In the code below, is calling `bar()` inside `foo.setBar(bar())` and `blah.setBar(bar())` using two difference instances of `Bar`? Or is it using `a bean instance` of `Bar` instead? If it's a bean instance, how does Spring do it automagically? Is it achieved by proxy?

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar(bar());
        return foo;
    }

    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar();
    }

    @Bean
    public Blah blah() {
        Blah blah = new Blah();
        blah.setBar(bar());
        return blah;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring creates a proxy of your @Configuration annotated classes. This proxy intercepts @Bean method calls and caches the bean instances so that further calls to the same @Bean method refers to the same bean instance.

Hence in your case both calls to bar() method refers to the same Bar instance.The Bar instance is actually a singleton per application context.This is why the @Bean methods visibility is restricted to either protected , package or public because Spring needs to override your @Bean methods in the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Single bean instance will be used and it is achieved using proxies. Spring uses the concept of **Inheritance based proxies** to achieve this. Please take a look at - [How to exactly work the Spring Inheritance-based Proxies configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935845/how-to-exactly-work-the-spring-inheritance-based-proxies-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

the same bean instance will be used in your case because a singleton scope is used by default for '@Bean' annotation.

yes, it's achived by spring proxying internals.